# conditional javascript execution based on browser window size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple jQuery function--detailed below-- that I'm using to manipulate the position of the document header, and I'm wondering if I can add a parameter such that the function is *only* executed if the browser window is of a certain size? In this case, I'd like the "stickyHeaderTop" function to execute only if the browser window width exceeds 1024px; is this possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('header').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                    $('header').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
            } else {
                    $('header').css({position: 'relative', top: '30px'});
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `window.screen.availWidth` attribute?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `screen`-Object's `height`, `width`, `availHeight` and `availWidth` attributes.

In case you want to execute some code on screens smaller than 800px for example just do:

```
if (screen.width < 800){
// do stuff
}
```

Be aware that this is an area that has some cross-browser pitfalls (and problems when having sth like the stumbleupon toolbar), so an alternative would be using jQuery (that you are already using) to detect your client's window size:

```
if ($(window).width() < 800){
// do stuff
}
```

Further reading at **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.screen.width)** regarding pure JS and **[jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/width/)** for the jQuery part

Comment: thanks m90-- still a js beginner here; that was pretty straightforward!

Answer (score 0):

You could place something like this in your `scroll` event callback.

```
If ($(window).width() < 1024) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, Alex; where exactly would I place this within the function?